# HTML select not selecting correct option from keyboard input

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have the following HTML

```html
<select name="mySelect">
    <option></option>
    <option>431</option>
    <option>444</option>
    <option>489</option>
</select>
```

When I click on the dropdown and manual type in 489 or 431, the correct option is selected.
But when I type in 444, for some reason the the 489 option is selected. I get the same behavior in Google Chrome, Edge, and Brave.

Is there anyway to modify this behavior?

Comment: when you hit 4 it selects the first item that begins with 4, when you hit it two times it is the second and so on. So hitting 4 three times will not select 444 but the third element that begins with 4 (489)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was trying to understand. That makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Use a datalist: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

```html
    <input list="numbers" />
    <datalist id="numbers">
        <option value="431"></option>
        <option value="444"></option>
        <option value="489"></option>
    </datalist>
```